# Is there a way to pivot tables with 2 aggregate functions through SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1(Start Table)

| ID | Date | Designation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/6 | a |
| 1 | 12/6 | b |
| 1 | 12/6 | c |
| 2 | 12/6 | d |
| 2 | 12/6 | e |
| 2 | 12/3 | f |
| 3 | 1/2 | g |
| 4 | 2/4 | h |

Table 2(Result)

| ID | Date | Designation1 | Designation2 | Designation3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/6 | a | b | c |
| 2 | 12/6 | d | e |  |
| 2 | 12/3 | f |  |  |
| 3 | 1/2 | g |  |  |
| 4 | 2/4 | h |  |  |

I am trying to pivot my tables in a way that could create multiple columns off of 2 criteria and achieve result from table 1 to table 2. Is this possible?

I have tried using regular pivot methods but end up with too many extra columns that I am not looking for.

Comment: Past your sample data as text.

Comment: Do you expect the output designations to be in alphabetic order as illustrated in your example? what mysql version are you using?

Comment: *a way to pivot tables with 2 aggregate functions through SQL* I do not see any aggregation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of `mysql` you are using.
we can use row_number per `ID` and `DATE`, then using conditional aggregation grouped by that row number:

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by ID, DATE) as row_id, t.*
  from mytable t
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    Date,
    MAX(CASE row_id WHEN 1 THEN Designation END) AS Designation1,
    MAX(CASE row_id WHEN 2 THEN Designation END) AS Designation2,
    MAX(CASE row_id WHEN 3 THEN Designation END) AS Designation3
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, Date
order by ID, DATE DESC;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IC_I0kJW)